# Missing start value

Tags: modelica

This is a [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64498571/the-initialization-system-is-structurally-singular). After I solved structurally singularity error. It throws me a new error saying

```
Hochdruckreiniger2 : Iteration variable "der(Hochdrucktank.V)" is missing start value!
Iteration variable "der(Hochdrucktank.medium.h)" is missing start value
Iteration variable "der(Niederdrucktank.V)" is missing start value!
Iteration variable "der(Niederdrucktank.medium.h)" is missing start value!
Iteration variable "der(Swept1.medium.p)" is missing start value!
```

Although I give start values in the initialization and initialize subsections, I get this error. Could you give me a suggestion on the solving this problem?

```
model Hochdruckreiniger2
    //Declaration(s)
    Real V_max = 0.000003;
    Real V_tod = 0.000002;
    Real pi = 3.14;
    Real N = 2800;
    Real T_per;
    Real f;
    Real opening_NP;
    Real opening_HP;
    //Component(s)
    Modelica.Fluid.Machines.SweptVolume Swept1 (
        pistonCrossArea = 0.0001131,
        clearance = 0.000002,
        portsData = {Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.BaseClasses.VesselPortsData(diameter=
        0.1),Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.BaseClasses.VesselPortsData(diameter=
        0.1)},
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater,
        nPorts = 2,
        use_portsData = true,
        p_start = 100,
        use_T_start = true,
        T_start = 293.15,
        V(start = 10),
        U(start = 20),
        m(start = 10));
    inner Modelica.Fluid.System system;
    Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.OpenTank Niederdrucktank (
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater,
        nPorts = 1,
        height = 40.84,
        crossArea = 10,
        portsData = {Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.BaseClasses.VesselPortsData(diameter=
        0.1)},
        V(start = 10));
    Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.OpenTank Hochdrucktank (
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater,
        nPorts = 1,
        height = 4997,
        crossArea = 10,
        portsData = {Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.BaseClasses.VesselPortsData(diameter=
        0.1)},
        V(start = 100));
    Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Sources.Position Posit1 (exact = true);
    Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Sine Sine1 (freqHz = 46.72, amplitude = 0.0000005);
    Modelica.Fluid.Valves.ValveIncompressible Hochdruckventile (
        dp_nominal = 66.6175,
        m_flow_nominal = 0.04873,
        rho_nominal = 1019.921,
        opening = opening_HP,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater);
    Modelica.Fluid.Valves.ValveIncompressible Niederdruckventile (
        dp_nominal = 65.21,
        m_flow_nominal = 0.04873,
        rho_nominal = 998.388,
        opening = opening_NP,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater);


equation
    T_per=pi/(180*3600*N/60);//Radian  
        f=((V_max-V_tod)/2)*sin((2*pi*time*T_per)+(V_tod+(V_max-V_tod)/2));
          if der(f)>=0 then
            opening_NP=1;
            opening_HP=0;
           else
            opening_NP=0;
            opening_HP=1;
          end if;
    //Connection(s)
    connect(Sine1.y, Posit1.s_ref);
    connect(Posit1.flange, Swept1.flange);
    connect(Hochdrucktank.ports[1], Hochdruckventile.port_a);
    connect(Hochdruckventile.port_b, Swept1.ports[2]);
    connect(Niederdrucktank.ports[1], Niederdruckventile.port_a);
    connect(Niederdruckventile.port_b, Swept1.ports[1]);
end  Hochdruckreiniger2;
```

Comment: You are giving a start value for V, not for der(V). Maybe introduce an initial equation section and set der(v)=0 there?

Comment: I write in initial equation section der(Hochdrucktank.V)=0;
der(Hochdrucktank.medium.h)=0;
der(Niederdrucktank.V)=0;
der(Niederdrucktank.medium.h)=0;
der(Swept1.medium.p)=0;
der(Swept1.medium.h)=0;  but it doesnt help to solve the problem

Comment: The initial section isn't for missing guess-values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To introduce a guess-value for a *derivative* you have to do something like the following in Modelica:

```
  Real dummyStart(start=...);
equation
  dummyStart=der(Hochdrucktank.V);
```

or possibly:

```
  Real dummyStart(start=...)=der(Hochdrucktank.V);
```

In some cases an extra variable is not needed as there already exists such a variable, and it's just a matter of finding it.

Comment: Thanks. It solves for der(Hochdrucktank.V). But I have still an error  for der(Niederdrucktank.medium.h),der(Hochdrucktank.medium.h),der(Swept1.medium.p). Is there any difference in coding for these derivatives?

Comment: Well, you have to have different names for them. In some cases it's an array variable so you have to write Real dummyStart2[..](start={...})=der(...); but I don't think that applies here. Finally it could be that it is protected and you cannot access it; unfortunately there's no real way around the latter.

Comment: I give different names but still I have this error. When it is protected, how should I deal with it?

Comment: There is, unfortunately, no good general solution if it is protected.

Comment: Which variable  do you mean protected ?

Comment: I meant that if the variable is protected it doesn't work. I haven't checked whether they are.